# Form data not populating in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, cordova

Here's the form:

```
<form id="secursendmsg" action="server.php" method="post">
        <div id="body_errors">
        </div>

        <textarea id="msg_body" name="msg_body'">
        </textarea>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function showMe (box) {

            var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("read");
            var vis = "none";
            for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) {

              if(chboxs[i].checked){
                vis = "block";
                break;
              }
            }
            document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;


          }
        </script>

        <p id="notifycheck" class="notify">
          <input type="checkbox" name="read" name="notify" onclick="showMe('notify')"/>

          <label for="id_notify">
            Enable Read Receipts
          </label>
        </p>
        <div id="notify" style="display:none">
          <div id="email_errors">
          </div>

          <div class="left">
            <p>
              <label for="email">
                Contact email (suggest Anonmail address):
              </label>

              <br>
              <input id="email" type="text" name="sender_email" size="35" rows="3" maxlength="100"/>
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
        <p id="pwrapper">
          <div class="button1">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Submit
        </div>

        <div class="settings">

          <i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size: 20px;">
          </i>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
```

My PHP code is below:

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect("192.99.xxx.xxx","root","LAxxxxxd!");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("SecurSend", $con);

  $sent = $_POST['msg_body'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];


  $sent = mysql_real_escape_string($sent);
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);




  $query = "
INSERT INTO `SecurSend`.`SecurMSG` (`email`,`sent`) VALUES         ('".$sent."','".$email."');";"

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>Test Complete!</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

No matter what, I never get the echo, and the information isn't populating. I can't wrap my head around why. The form & PHP isn't hosted on the server, it is hosted in-app via Cordova.

Comment: `('".$sent."','".$email."');";"` <= extra quote and using the wrong POST variable for "email". Having error reporting set and checking for error on query would have signaled those.

Comment: `$email = $_POST['sender_email'];`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`; which are invaluable tools you should be using when developing.

Comment: I knew you were waiting for me to say....Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Submit` - How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Okay, I added error reporting, I am receiving the echo, but it shows as:
Test Complete!"; or die(mysql_error()) mysql_close($con); } ?>

Comment: @Autonomous is the database getting updated

Comment: "Test Complete!"; or die(mysql_error()) mysql_close($con); } ?>" that shows up as code? Is your file `.php` extension? Something is not right.

Comment: Yeah, the file name is server.php. I'm not sure what's going on here..

Comment: Ok, I think I know why. `<?` isyour opening (PHP) tag. It seems that short open tags are not set. You will need to change that to `<?php`. Once you've done that, continue with error reporting. Or, changing it to `<?php` may very well fix your code.

Comment: Did that, I'm still receiving the same output.

Comment: Create a `test.php` file with `<?php echo "Hello world.";` if that doesn't echo "Hello world.", you have a server issue.

Comment: Doesn't echo, does the PHP HAVE to be hosted on the server as opposed to being included in the app package on the device?

Comment: Both files need to be inside your server. If you're trying to access someone else's server, then that could explain it. You could also try Ajax/Curl.

Comment: I am using Cordova. The site files are being accessed directly on the Android device. What would be the proper way of sending data from the Android device, to the database?

Comment: That I couldn't help you with. I know nothing about Android. You will need to Google it, where you're most likely going to end up back on Stack from Q&A's found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `email` text name issue, your sql line is messed up:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO SecurSend.SecurMSG(email,sent)VALUES('".$sent."','".$email."')";
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. The syntax is showing correctly now, however, no data is being populated. Thanks for catching the email error, I'm only testing with msg_body at the moment & that's not going through.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
```

to

```
$email = $_POST['sender_email'];
```

You have named email in the form as `sender_email` and you used `email` in php.

Also you have an extra double quote in the `$query` string. After removing that code will be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO SecurSend.SecurMSG(email,sent)VALUES('".$sent."','".$email."')";
```

As far as the code you have shown you are not submitting the form.

So change

```
<div class="button1">
     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Submit
</div>
```

to

```
<button class="button1" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Submit
</button>
```

Comment: I'm wondering how OP is submitting the form. This `<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Submit` is hard to say whether OP is trying to use that which doesn't qualify as a submit button. Probably a contributing factor.

Comment: Yeah I did catch that, but forgot to throw it in here. I am using a different button for testing purposes.

    <button type="submit" form="secursendmsg" value="Submit">Submit</button>

Comment: @Autonomous Are you by any chance reading the comments left under your question? Specifically the one about [checking for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132811/form-data-not-populating-in-mysql-database#comment42764580_27132811).

Comment: @Fred-ii-Nope, just saw that now. Kinda still getting used to Stack Overflow's interface. I'll try that.